# Request method GET not supported when deleting

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a table for adding one object to another and deleting one object from another.

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/proj/{pid}/coupling/{r1}")
public class CouplingController {


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllCouplings( ){   
        return "riskCoupling";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{r1}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCoupling( ){
        return "/projects";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{r2}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String removeCoupling(){

        return "/projects";
    }
}
```

This is my Thymeleaf view

```html
<td>
    <form action = "#" th:action="@{/proj/{pid}/coupling/{r1}/{r2} (pid=${projectID},r1=${r1ID},r2=${r2.id})}" method = "post">
        <input type="submit" name="Couple" value="Couple" class="btn btn-info" />
    </form>
</td>
<td">
    <form action = "#" th:action="@{/proj/{pid}/coupling/{r1}/{r2} (pid=${projectID},r1=${r1ID},r2=${r2.id})}" method = "delete">
        <input type="submit" name="RemoveCoupling" value="RemoveCoupling" class="btn btn-info" />
    </form>
</td>
```

When I go to the url `/proj/{pid}/coupling/{r1}` I get the overview so the GET works.

When I press the Couple button it works. So the POST works.

When I press the RemoveCoupling button I get the error:

```
Request method "Get" not supported.
```

I really don't know why I get this error.

Comment: Possible you have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629653/using-put-and-delete-methods-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with [Thymeleaf - Button click to call http delete method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370011/thymeleaf-button-click-to-call-http-delete-method).

Basically putting a hidden field in my form.

Answer (score 1):

Since browsers unfortunately do not support any other verbs than POST and GET in HTML forms, they will just send POST/GET requests instead. This might be the reason why only that one does not work.

See more:

- http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html
- http://amundsen.com/examples/put-delete-forms/
- http://www.quora.com/HTTP/Why-are-PUT-and-DELETE-no-longer-supported-in-HTML5-forms