# Why my Thymeleaf Delete Button does GET/POST instead of DELETE?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My thymeleaf delete button is executing either a **GET** or a **POST** request without understanding why.

I'm using those starters:

- *Spring Boot*
- *Spring Security*
- *Spring JPA*
- *Spring Web*

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

// [...]

@DeleteMapping("/users/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

        userDeletionService.deleteUserById(id);

        return "redirect:/users/list";
    }
}
```

Here's the first tried button using an attribute(*user*) passed to the template:

```
<a th:href="@{'/users/delete/{id}'(id=${user.id})}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

Falling on **error 405** and we can notice that it did a **GET**:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /users/delete/18    
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
```

Here, I'm trying a sedond button:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/users/delete/{id}'(id=${user.id})}" th:method="delete" >
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton"> </button>
</form>
```

Falling again on error 405 but, this time, it did a **POST**:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured POST /users/delete/18
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
```

Comment: Links (`<a>`) are always `GET`, forms can be `GET` or `POST`. To issue a `DELETE` you'd have to use JavaScript (AJAX).

Comment: @slauth Thank you so much for the clarity of your explanation! It should be more referenced not loosing too much time on debugging. I'll try this out and get right back.

Comment: Thanks again to @slauth. What worked for me was Raphael Roussis's answer on the following link (thanks to him as well): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370011/thymeleaf-button-click-to-call-http-delete-method

Answer (score 0):

HTML can only use GET or POST by default. Spring Boot and Thymeleaf support a workaround via the HiddenHttpMethodFilter.

To use it, you need to do 2 things:

1. Add `th:method="delete"` on your form:

```
<form th:method="delete" ... >
```

Thymeleaf will automatically insert a hidden input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
```

2. Enable the filter in Spring Boot. The easiest way is adding this to `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```